# Blender 2.8 Viewport Render Image is dark and different to actual viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting, render-passes

When I render the viewport from "View > Viewport Render Image" it appears different and far darker.

[image: viewport image render]

Images are darkened in wireframe and solid mode but not in material preview or rendered preview (cycles / evee).

HOWEVER, if any other render passes beside "Combined" is chosen then it then starts to appear darkened if viewport rendered.

[image]

Viewport shot here is darkened

[image]

Viewport shot in combined mode is completely fine, however, there is no color in the X & Y grid, likely darkened like the rest.

[image]

Unsure if this is related to the same problem, but the little preview window in the materials panel has also been darkened.

to clarify, this problem is only happening in this specific blender file. A new blend file does not exhibit any of these problems. Restarting the computer and or blend file does not fix anything, and I am unsure as to when this started happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. Navigate to Properties editor ‣ Render ‣ [Color Management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/render/color_management.html?highlight=color%20management) - If you have changed the settings in there it will affect the render, but not the viewport view. Using the sub-option *curves* You can set the rendered picture to appear similar to the viewport. It helped in my case.Hope it helps you too.

Comment: ok, I fixed my comment. Sorry for the trouble.